# Scala Collections: transforming a List into a Map

Tags: scala, collections

I need to transform a collection like this one

```
case class Entity( year: Int, month: Int )

List( Entity(2013,01), Entity(2013,01), Entity(2013,03),
      Entity(2013,02), Entity(2013,02), Entity(2013,02),
      Entity(2014,07) )
```

in a collection like this one:

```
Map( 2013 -> List(01,03,02) , 2014 -> List(07) )
```

that is a Map with years as keys and a list of the months (only one occurrence) as values.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple with a `groupBy` opertaion:

```
case class Entity( year: Int, month: Int )

val entities = List( Entity(2013,01), Entity(2013,01), Entity(2013,03),
    Entity(2013,02), Entity(2013,02), Entity(2013,02),
    Entity(2014,07) )

val mappedEntities = entities.groupBy(_.year)
                             .mapValues(list => list.map(_.month).distinct)

mappedEntities: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = 
  Map(2014 -> List(7), 2013 -> List(1, 3, 2))
```

Comment: Add `.distinct` after `.map(_.month)` to reduce the month lists to one entry per unique month as per the question.